# How to cancel/remove all print requests from print server in Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, printing

In Solaris 10, how can I cancel/remove all print requests from print server?

I know I can delete all entries in `/var/spool/lp/localhost`, but is there a better way than to clobber all?

Answer (score 0):

It appears running a simple

```
lprm -
```

would do what you want.

Per the [`lprm` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/lprm-1b.html#scrolltoc) to remove print jobs:

> **lprm**
>
> remove print requests from the print queue
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> /usr/ucb/lprm [-P destination] [-] [request-ID]... 
> [user]...
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The lprm utility removes print requests (request-ID) from the print
> queue.
>
> Without arguments, lprm deletes the current print request. lprm
> reports the name of the file associated with print requests that it
> removes. lprm is silent if there are no applicable print requests to
> remove.
>
> Users can only remove print requests associated with their user name.
> See Notes. If a superuser executes lprm and specifies the user
> operand, lprm removes all print requests belonging to the specified
> user.
>
> The print client commands locate destination information using the
> “printers” database in the name service switch. See nsswitch.conf(4),
> printers(4), and printers.conf(4) for details.
>
> **Options**
>
> The following options are supported:
>
> -P destination
>
> The name of the printer or class of printers (see lpadmin(1M)) from
> which to remove print requests. Specify destination using atomic,
> URI-style (scheme://endpoint), or POSIX-style (server:destination)
> names. See printers.conf(4) for information regarding the naming
> naming conventions for destination names.
>
> -
>
> If a user specifies this option, removes all print requests owned by
> that user. If a superuser specifies this option, removes all requests
> in the print queue. Job ownership is determined by the user's login
> name and host name on the machine from which lpr was executed. See
> Notes.
>
> **Operands**
>
> The following operands are supported.
>
> *request-ID*
>
> Removes a specific print request. Specify request-ID as the job number
> (Job) associated with a print request and reported by lpq. See
> lpq(1B). user
>
> - Removes print requests associated with a specific user. Specify
> user as a valid user name. This option can only be used by a
> superuser.

You can also use [`lpq` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/lpq-1b.html#scrolltoc) to display print queues before you nuke them.

Comment: Both commands give:  Failed to contact server for _default: not found